# How do I create a grid filled row by row from the pattern provided by the one-dimensional pattern passed in

Tags: java, grid, row, multiple-columns, qr-code

Whenever I try to compile this code that sets the grid for a QR code I get an error: Cannot load from object array because "QRCode.grid" is null at QRCode.setGrid(QRCode.java:76). I think there is an error in the last line.

```java
public void setGrid(int dim, int [] pattern) {
        if(pattern==null)
             
         grid=new int[dim][dim];
         
         for(int row=0;row<dim;row++) {
             for(int col = 0; col < dim; col++) {
                 
                 grid[i][j]=pattern[row*dim+col];
            
                } 
            }
    
    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell from the snippet of code, but presumably `grid` is `null`. Where do you initialise it when `pattern` isn't `null`?

Comment: If you learn to indent your code correctly (or learn how to ask your IDE to do it) you'll find the code you write becomes easier to understand.